# any lightweight image cropping software that shows pixel measurements

Tags: image-editor

I have a lot of very large images that need cropping to precise resolutions. the windows photos app doesn't show pixels and I don't want to open photoshop every time.

Answer (score 1):

gThumb seems to do it, in the right sidebar

Screenshot is included below:

[image]

Relevant pages:

- at Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GThumb
- at FSF Directory https://directory.fsf.org/wiki/Gthumb
- official web site https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gthumb